# Vue JS: Property or method "vehcile" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Tags: vue.js

I am learning Vue and trying to create a small app. I am getting the following error:

> Property or method "vehicle" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.

In my App.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
      <Header title="Test" />
      <Vehicles :vehicles="vehicles"/>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import Header from './components/Header'
import Vehicles from './components/Vehicles'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    Header,
    Vehicles
  },
  data(){
    return {
      vehicles: []
    }
  },
  created(){
    this.vehicles = [
      {
        id: 1,
        model: 'Volks swagen', 
        date: 'March 1st 2021',
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        model: 'Lamborghini', 
        date: 'March 3rd 2021',
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        model: 'Porsche', 
        date: 'March 27th 2021',
      }
    ]
  }
}
</script>
```

In my Vehicles.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
       <div :v-for="vehicle in vehicles"></div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default{
    name: 'Vehicles',
    props: {
        vehicles: Array
    }
}
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `<div :v-for="vehicle in vehicles">` should just be `<div v-for="vehicle in vehicles">`

Comment: @bassxzero That gives error : Elements in iteration expect to have 'v-bind:key' directives

Comment: So add a `key` directive. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Maintaining-State

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `vehicles.vue` file must be done like this.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="vehicle in vehicles" :key="vehicle.id">
      <div>{{ vehicle.model }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: "Vehicles",
    props: {
      vehicles: {
        type: Array,
        default: () => [],
      },
    },
  };
</script>
```

Comment: It gives the data but also gives error : Type of the default value for 'vehicles' prop must be a function